# Interaction between k8s custom controller and etcd using API server

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, etcd

I am trying to write a CRD in k8s and I am trying to have my custom controller talk to etcd. I noticed that the k8s docs mention that only the API server should have access to communication with etcd for security purposes. In this case, how should my controller communicate with etcd using the api server? I was not able to find a k8s api that is used for etcd

Comment: You wouldn't usually interact with etcd directly.  You can keep a limited amount of state in your custom resource's `status` block, or deduce it from the current state of the cluster.  What are you hoping to do with it?

Comment: I am hoping to create a CRD that shares a lock across the different k8s clusters

Comment: Those will likely have separate etcds in any case.  You could deploy your own etcd, if you had a way to communicate between the clusters, but the Kubernetes-internal etcd isn't accessible.